# Spliting dataframe into chunks by the rows that satisfy the given condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to:

```
 col1   col2
 1      10
 1      30
 2      60
 3      20
 3      12
 3      51
 3      11
```

I want to divide this dataframe into chanks when the value in col2 is bigger than 50:

```
dataframe #1    
col1   col2
1      10
1      30
2      60

dataframe #2
col1   col2
3      20
3      12
3      51

dataframe #3
col1   col2
3      11
```

I have tried `split` function but it would not serve for this task. I wonder if there is a generic function to achieve this?

Comment: I was wondering how you want to handle if there are multiple values above 50 in a row. I.e., if `col2 = c(10, 30, 60, 61, 20)` do you want to have 2 chunks `10, 30, 60, 61` and `20` or 3 chunks `10, 30, 60`, `61`, and `20`.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` in `split`, with a lot of `rev`ing to include the rows where col2 > 50 in the previous group

```
rev(split(df, rev(cumsum(rev(df$col2 > 50)))))
#@joran method, (same result, except for names): 
split(df, cumsum(df$col2 > 50) - (df$col2 > 50))
```

Output:

```
# $`2`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1   10
# 2:    1   30
# 3:    2   60
# 
# $`1`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    3   20
# 2:    3   12
# 3:    3   51
# 
# $`0`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    3   11
```

without all the `rev`s you get this

```
split(df, cumsum(df$col2 > 50))

# $`0`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1   10
# 2:    1   30
# 
# $`1`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    2   60
# 2:    3   20
# 3:    3   12
# 
# $`2`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    3   51
# 2:    3   11
```

Comment: An alternative, probably no more/less complicated: `cumsum(df$col2 > 50) - (df$col2 > 50)`.

Comment: thanks! Without help, it was really impossible to figure this out myself..