# Calculate time to event from event indicator variable

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to calculate the relative time to an Event. I have the following MWE:

```
library(data.table)
dt.MWE <- structure(list(Year = 2000:2015, Event = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
                                       1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                       0L)), row.names = c(NA, -16L)
                            , class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
                             ,  index = structure(integer(0), "`__Year`" = integer(0)))

    Year Event
 1: 2000     0
 2: 2001     0
 3: 2002     0
 4: 2003     0
 5: 2004     1
 6: 2005     0
 7: 2006     0
 8: 2007     0
 9: 2008     0
10: 2009     0
11: 2010     1
12: 2011     0
13: 2012     0
14: 2013     0
15: 2014     0
16: 2015     0
```

Based on this I would like to add another column `Time.to.Event`, which is a variable relative to the point in time the event happened. So that the Variable in 2003 is -1, 2002 is -2, 2001 is -3 and 2000 is -4.
But after the event happened it should either become positive, when no future event happens, like in 2011 it should become 1, or it should be negative relative to the next future event.
The resulting data.table should look like this:

```
    Year Event Time.to.Event
 1: 2000     0            -4
 2: 2001     0            -3
 3: 2002     0            -2
 4: 2003     0            -1
 5: 2004     1             0
 6: 2005     0            -5
 7: 2006     0            -4
 8: 2007     0            -3
 9: 2008     0            -2
10: 2009     0            -1
11: 2010     1             0
12: 2011     0             1
13: 2012     0             2
14: 2013     0             3
15: 2014     0             4
16: 2015     0             5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt.MWE)

dt.MWE[, Time.to.Event :=  seq(.N) - ifelse(any(Event), .N, 0L)
       , by = cumsum(Event) - Event]


#     Year Event Time.to.Event
#  1: 2000     0            -4
#  2: 2001     0            -3
#  3: 2002     0            -2
#  4: 2003     0            -1
#  5: 2004     1             0
#  6: 2005     0            -5
#  7: 2006     0            -4
#  8: 2007     0            -3
#  9: 2008     0            -2
# 10: 2009     0            -1
# 11: 2010     1             0
# 12: 2011     0             1
# 13: 2012     0             2
# 14: 2013     0             3
# 15: 2014     0             4
# 16: 2015     0             5
```

Comment: I like the smart way of constructing group var with `cumsum(Event) - Event`. I usually do this with two `rev`.

Comment: Got that tip from joran here on SO :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620924/spliting-dataframe-into-chunks-by-the-rows-that-satisfy-the-given-condition/51621017#51621017

Comment: Another option: `dt.MWE[, Time.to.Event := (1:.N) - c(0,.N)[sum(Event) + 1], by = cumsum(shift(Event, fill = 0))]`

Comment: Is there perhaps a better headline for the question, which is more general?

Comment: Maybe "Calculate time to event from event indicator variable"?

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
dt.MWE[, Time.to.Event := (1:.N) - c(0,.N)[sum(Event) + 1]
       , by = cumsum(shift(Event, fill = 0))][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dt.MWE
>     Year Event Time.to.Event
>  1: 2000     0            -4
>  2: 2001     0            -3
>  3: 2002     0            -2
>  4: 2003     0            -1
>  5: 2004     1             0
>  6: 2005     0            -5
>  7: 2006     0            -4
>  8: 2007     0            -3
>  9: 2008     0            -2
> 10: 2009     0            -1
> 11: 2010     1             0
> 12: 2011     0             1
> 13: 2012     0             2
> 14: 2013     0             3
> 15: 2014     0             4
> 16: 2015     0             5
> ```

Comment: `(1:.N) - c(0,.N)[sum(Event) + 1]` i'm said I cant upvote more than once.